# Return from a shell function that uses a make variable

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have the following makefile

```
.ONESHELL:

p3:
    @VAR1=$(shell cat meow) # first file
    @echo "$${VAR1}"
    @VAR2=$(shell grep -oP "name:\s*\K.+" file2)
    @echo "$${VAR2}"
#   @VAR3=$(shell grep -oP "name:\s*\K.+" $${VAR1})
#   @echo "$${VAR3}"
```

And

```
echo -e "file2" > meow
echo -e "name: My_Name" > file2
```

When I run `make p3`, I see:

```
$ make p3
file2
My_Name
```

Which is great.  However, what I really want is not to hardcode "file2" in the makefile, but to receive it from the contents of the 'meow' file.

when I uncomment the line the calls for `$${VAR1}`, the program hangs indefinitely.  No way of escaping that variable seems to work either, `$VAR1`, `$$VAR1`, `$(VAR1)`, `$$(VAR1)`, `${VAR1}`, `$${VAR1}` all fail.

How can I get a return value from a shell function that uses a make variable?  If this requires `define` I'm open to that, too.

Comment: Renaud's answer is quite correct but just to call out: the exact reason for your problem is that make must expand all make variables and make functions FIRST, **before** it passes your recipe to the shell to be run (if you think about it this is quite obvious).  That means that all the `$(shell ...)` functions must be run first, before the shell is invoked...which means the shell variable `$VAR1` is not set when those functions are expanded.  See point #1 in Renaud's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make recipes are shell scripts, using the `shell` function in a make recipe is always wrong. The behavior is not the same because make expands the recipes before passing them to the shell, not during their execution by the shell. Do not write:

   ```
   VAR2=$(shell grep -oP "name:\s*\K.+" file2)
   ```

   Write:

   ```
   VAR2=`grep -oP "name:\s*\K.+" file2`
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   VAR2=$$(grep -oP "name:\s*\K.+" file2)
   ```

   (the double `$$` is needed to escape the expansion of the recipes by make before it passes them to the shell).
2. It is better to not silence your recipe with `@`, especially when you are debugging your Makefile. Prefer the equivalent make options or special targets (`-s` and `.SILENT` with GNU make).
3. You should probably quote your shell expansions (e.g., the `$${VAR1}` in `grep -oP "name:\s*\K.+" $$VAR1)`.

So, for your Makefile you could try the following:

```
.ONESHELL:

# Uncomment the following line when done
#.SILENT:

p3:
    VAR1=`cat meow`
    echo "$${VAR1}"
    VAR2=`grep -oP "name:\s*\K.+" file2`
    echo "$${VAR2}"
    VAR3=`grep -oP "name:\s*\K.+" "$${VAR1}"`
    echo "$${VAR3}"
```

Comment: They are using `.ONESHELL` so the entire thing is passed to a single shell.  Also when you say "not silence your recipe with `$`" ITYM `@` (but you're quite right)

Comment: Ooops, you're right, they use `.ONESHELL:`. I must fix my answer.